# Link two actions together with Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter

I want to make a bot that, when it detects a new tweet from a specific account (as an example in my code: NASA), does an action on my keyboard (with the keyboard import). The problem is that I don't know how to link the two. I'm sure I'll have to use an "if" but the API of twitter python version (tweepy) is difficult to understand.

````
import keyboard
import tweepy
import auth
 
#Use the twitter Api to read if there is a new tweet
api.user_timeline(screen_name="NASA")
 
 
#action of my keyboard that performs the action of pressing f11
 
keyboard.send("F11")
print("New tweet, F11 was pressed.")```
````

Answer (score 0):

As the API says [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline), that method returns a collection of the most recent tweets. You can try to run something like:

```
import keyboard
import tweepy
import auth

collection_of_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name="NASA")
print("Whatever_the_string")
```

Put a breakpoint on the print line in your code editor and then hover over collection_of_tweets. That should show you the value for that name.
Then, maybe store the last tweet in another name and running an script every X seconds, days, or whatever checking if the last tweet that you have stored is equal (maybe compare the timestamp of the two tweets and not the entire object) to the last one you are receiving from the method.